# WPF Drag and Drop object from listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

beginner here.

I'm trying to create a usercontrol with one listbox among other control and I want this listbox to allow drag and drop to other similar instance of the usercontrol.

This is the object I want to drag and drop from one listbox to another :

```
[Serializable]
public class ListBoxFileName : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    private string FileNameValue;
    public string FileName
    {
        get { return this.FileNameValue; }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.FileNameValue)
            {
                this.FileNameValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("FileName");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool FileIsSelectedValue;
    public bool FileIsSelected
    {
        get { return this.FileIsSelectedValue; }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.FileIsSelectedValue)
            {
                this.FileIsSelectedValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("FileIsSelected");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I deal with the drag and drop :

```
    private ListBoxItem _dragged;

    private void FileNameList_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_dragged != null)
            return;

        UIElement element = FileNameList.InputHitTest(e.GetPosition(FileNameList)) as UIElement;
        while (element != null)
        {
            if (element is ListBoxItem)
            {
                _dragged = (ListBoxItem)element;
                break;
            }
            element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement;
        }
    }


    private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_dragged == null)
            return;
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
        {
            _dragged = null;
            return;
        }
        DataObject obj = new DataObject(DataFormats.Serializable, _dragged);
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(_dragged, obj, DragDropEffects.All);
    }

    private void FileNameList_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_dragged == null || e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Serializable, true) == false)
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
        else
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.All;
    }

    private void FileListBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, true))
        {
            string[] droppedFilePaths = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];
            for (var i = 0; i < droppedFilePaths.Length; i++)
            {
                ListBoxFileName filename = new ListBoxFileName();
                filename.FileName = droppedFilePaths[i];
                filename.FileIsSelected = false;
                FileNamesItems.Add(filename);
            }
        }
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Serializable, true))
        {
            ListBoxFileName BoxItem = new ListBoxFileName();
            BoxItem = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable) as ListBoxFileName;
        }
    }
```

Everything is fine except when the drop event occurs, `BoxItem` is always null for some reason, so nothing is added to the listbox.

Any hint ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried gong-wpf-dragdrop from https://www.nuget.org/packages/gong-wpf-dragdrop/ ? Source code is also awailable so you can look how it was implemented

Comment: @bamanow, the nuget of gong-wpf depends on WPFToolkit package, and this package depends on .NET 3.5. It's not compatible with .NET 4.0 or later.

Comment: @Eriawan you're wrong, instead starting with .NET 4.0 it doesn't have any dependencies

Answer (score 1):

The data of the DataObject should be a ListBoxFileName instead of a ListBoxItem:

```
private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (_dragged == null)
        return;
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
    {
        _dragged = null;
        return;
    }
    DataObject obj = new DataObject(DataFormats.Serializable, _dragged.DataContext as ListBoxFileName);
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(_dragged, obj, DragDropEffects.All);
}

private void FileListBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Serializable, true))
    {
        ListBoxFileName BoxItem = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable) as ListBoxFileName;
        //...
    }
}
```

This should work assuming that the ItemsSource of the "FileNameList" control is set to an IEnumerable.

Please provide all relevant code snippets required to be able to reproduce your issue from scratch if you need any further help on this.

Comment: thanks it is "partially" working. Indeed now when I select one of the copy of a BoxItem, then it is selected in every listbox. Any idea where this could come from ?

Comment: The same ListBoxFileName object is the DataContext of the two different visual containers so when you set its IsSelected property (or whatever you call it), both containers will be selected since they are bound to the very same property. If you don't want this you should clone, i.e. create a copy of, the ListBoxFileName object before you add it to the second ListBox.

Comment: That's great. Please remember to accept the answer.